# How to fix the character's clothing to remain stable and intact all the time?

Tags: rigging

1.The garment was torn and destroyed during the walk, how can it be arranged that the garment remains intact and functions as a normal garment?

2. In the rander Mode[image] The character is transparent when there is light on it - how do you fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please be more precise? Your cloth doesn't seem to be transparent. You should merge by distance in order to avoid the gap, also maybe create a pin group, and parent to the armature

Comment: Thanks, I meant the figure was transparent, not the clothes. If you go to render mode you can see that in the light the figure is transparent.
What did you mean by 'merge by
 distance'  you mean the vertices?

Comment: Unplug the image from the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF? As for the merge by distance, yes, I meant do it for the cloth

Comment: I will try, thank you!